# ISO8583 message header generate

Tags: iso8583

How I can  define the TPDU message header in ISO 8583?

Can any one suggest references or any code sample?

Comment: ISO 8583 is only core messages definitions. In the real live service providers used customized messages, sometimes with message headers. They are different depending of protocol implementations. Please clarify your requirements to use TPDU header or postpone it until your fully clear your project and ISO 8583 message and package content.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the payment schemes/EFT Switches use header in ISO8583 message. There is no restriction for number of bytes in tpdu header. Most of the EFT switches use 5 Byte TPDU header 1 byte(0x60) + 2 bytes source address + 2 Byte destination address. Few switches also uses 10 byte header (They take 2 byte iso8583 version in transaction header).

Message Length (2 Byte - 4BCD) + Header (5 Bytes) + MTI(2 Bytes - 4BCD Pack) + Bitmap(8 to 24 Bytes) + Fields data.

Answer (score 1):

as you may know the ISO8583 has a message type (4 bytes), before that you have to set the TPDU. It's usually formed by 7 bytes:

```
//2 bytes <len of the message, without include these 2 bytes>
//1 bytes <usually 60 hexadecimal>
//2 byte <origin's adress>
//2 byte <destiny's adress>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: It is only one example from many other headers used by financial protocols based on ISO 8583 and not a most used.

Comment: ISO 8583 MTI - Message Type could be 4 bytes in case ASCII or EBCDIC field formats. It could be also 2 bytes in case BCD format.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport Yes, just trying to bring a simple example of the structure.